# Getting browser login prompt when navigating to certain controller in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a number of controllers, one of which is called Reports.

When I try to navigate to /Reports or any other view inside /Reports, e.g. /Reports/MonthlyReport, I get the browser's login prompt for some reason:

[image]

I am using the exact same [Authorise] attribute on the controller that I use on all the other controllers, but they don't have this problem.

I don't have a physical folder called Reports.

I am not doing anything special inside this controller.

UPDATE: Here's the kicker: when I change the controller name from ReportsController to ReportController and the appropriate Views folder, the problem goes away.

I have made 0 changes to RouteConfig.

Comment: Do you have a specific route defined for the reports? Do you have user roles?

Comment: No RouteConfig is 100% the same generic setup as it was when I generated the project 6 months ago. Yes, I have user roles, though the reports controller is accessible to any logged in user. Also, simply changing its name solved the problem (but I'm affraid it might come back).